# msmtp cannot write to /var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log

Tags: server, permissions, email

In `/etc/msmtprc` I added credentials for a gmail account and also specified a log file to use in `/var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log`

I also created the folder and file in `/var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log`

When I test it using: `echo "This is a test e-mail from my server using msmtp!" | msmtp ******@gmail.com`

I receive an email but in the terminal I also see an error message like so: `msmtp: cannot log to /var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log: cannot open: Permission denied`

The current permissions for `/var/log/msmtp` are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root        4096 Jan 29 20:19 msmtp
```

What am I doing wrong? What do the permissions on the log file need to be for msmtp to be able to write to the file?

Comment: Is it similar to this question?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146466/as-what-user-does-a-command-end-up-executing

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error message, and ultimately changing permissions, creating the log file, etc., didn't work. The problem in my case was caused by AppArmor: in my system, the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp` only listed `/var/log/msmtp` as write permission in `/var/log`, so solution can be:

- to use `/var/log/msmtp` as log in the configuration, instead of `/var/log/msmtp.log`
- modify the rules in the `msmtp` `apparmor` profile to allow adding and locking the file we want.

Comment: Thanks! That was the case for me as well after upgrading from Debian 9 to Debian 10, where an apparmor config for msmtp was added.

Comment: Had the same problem.  Finally had to set the log to ~/.msmtp.log.  Could not understand why AppArmor was not letting me use /var/log/msmtp or /var/log/msmtp/msmtop.log

Answer (score 3):

After installing msmtp there is an *msmtp* user and group. If you change the ownership of the logfile to msmtp, and change rights to read/write for user and group, the logging works.

```
groups msmtp
sudo touch /var/log/msmtp
sudo chown msmtp:msmtp /var/log/msmtp
sudo chmod 660 /var/log/msmtp
```

I haven't tested it, but I suppose this works for /var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log as well, if you set the rights for the folder properly.

Comment: Very helpful and hard to find information. It seems to me that almost nobody knows this simple solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to have my email logs in `/var/log/mail.log` because that's the default in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and I wanted to avoid modifying apparmor config if possible, so I removed `logfile` and added this to `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
# The logs will appear in /var/log/mail.log because of the rules in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
syslog LOG_MAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

On a laptop running Debian stable, I also had the permission denied error. I set the log to be ~/var/msmtp.log. It was caused by apparmor as well. To correct it, I found the log lines in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp:

```
  owner @{HOME}/.msmtp*.log wk,
  /var/log/msmtp            wk,
```

I copied the first line above to the usr.bin.msmtp in /etc/apparmor.d/local and edited it to point to my log location:

```
  owner @{HOME}/var/msmtp*.log wk,
```

I rebooted because I didn't take the time to figure out how to get apparmor to read the updated files. Now it logs properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with 0640 but it did not work, it workd only with 0770
(I chowned with user msmtp + 0640, but it did not work either)

```
# mkdir /var/log/msmtp
# chmod -R 0770 /var/log/msmtp
# [nano|vim] /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp
  owner /var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log wk,

# service apparmor restart
$ echo 'message test mail backup' | msmtp the.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Running on Debian Bullseye,
I have tried to pull together various solutions posted here and elsewhere which in themselves are
both good practice and any one of which may solve the problem in some circumstances.
I am hoping that with the addition of my discovery every instance of error should be covered.

First:
Add users to "mail" group

```
sudo adduser nobody mail
```

Second:
Set log & configuration file path and permissions.

```
sudo touch /var/log/msmtp
sudo chown -R root:mail /var/log/msmtp
sudo chmod -R 660 /var/log/msmtp
sudo chown root:msmtp /etc/msmtprc
sudo chmod 640 /etc/msmtprc
```

Finally:
When I looked at my configuration file /etc/msmtprc I found that I had specified the log file path
incorrectly:

```
#SET PATH TO LOG FILE
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

Once this was corrected to....

```
#SET PATH TO LOG FILE
logfile /var/log/msmtp
```

and tested

```
echo 'message test mail backup' | msmtp the.email
```

The error message was finally gone.
Sadly msmtp was sending emails to tell me about a degraded RAID array.